# Adding characters after a certain word in Python using regex

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a text file and every time that the word "get" occurs, I need to insert an `@` sign after it.

How do I add a character after a specific word using regex?

Comment: do you want to add an `@` after `midget` ?

Comment: I do not want to add after midget. Does that change the regex?

Comment: Yes, a little. Martijn Pieters has the good answer. You only need to add word boundaries before and after the word "get" in the pattern: `\bget\b`

Answer (score 54):

Use `re.sub()` to provide replacements, using a backreference to re-use matched text:

```
import re

text = re.sub(r'(get)', r'\1@', text)
```

The `(..)` parenthesis mark a group, which `\1` refers to when specifying a replacement. So `get` is replaced by `get@`.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'Do you get it yet?'
>>> re.sub(r'(get)', r'\1@', text)
'Do you get@ it yet?'
```

The pattern will match `get` anywhere in the string; if you need to limit it to whole words, add `\b` anchors:

```
text = re.sub(r'(\bget\b)', r'\1@', text)
```

Comment: ♦: How to pass `get ` in a variable?
I mean how to set `pass_variable_dynamically = "get"` `#may be some other string`
re.sub(r'pass_variable_dynamically', r'\1@', text)) not working

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak: you mean you want to parameterise the regex? Escape your variable with `re.escape()` and use normal string interpolation techniques:  `re.sub(r'(\b{}\b)'.format(variable), r'\1@', text)` would use `variable` to obtain the word to replace.

Comment: With f-strings, it will be `re.sub(rf'(\b{variable}\b), r'\1@', text)`

Answer (score 0):

To insert a character after every occurrence of a string (`'get'`), you don’t even need regex. Split on `'get'` and concatenate with `'@get'` in between strings.

```py
text = 'Do you get it yet?'
'get@'.join(text.split('get'))            # 'Do you get@ it yet?'
```

However, if `'get'` has to be an entire word, `re.split()` could be used instead.

```py
text = 'Did you get it or forget?'
'get@'.join(re.split(r"\bget\b", text))   # 'Did you get@ it or forget?'
```

Comment: I don't see how joining `re.split` results is any simpler than using `re.sub`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I meant `str.split` was simpler. I agree, `re.split` is not simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace (zero-width) matches of `(?<=\bget\b)` with `'@'`.

```
import re
```

```
text = re.sub(r'(?<=\bget\b)', '@', text)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FaeQuK/1)

`(?<=\bget\b)` is a *positive lookbehind*. It asserts that the (zero-width) match is immediately preceded by `'get'`. The *word boundaries* `\b` are added to prevent matching that string when it is immediately preceded and/or followed by a word character (such as `'budget'`, `'getting'` or `'nuggets'`).