# Regex adding characters before another word (from a list of choices)

Tags: python, regex, string

I was reading [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735384/regex-python-adding-characters-after-a-certain-word), which gave me the idea to use groups. 
I want to add a \t before the characters that come after /O, /ORGANIZATION, /PEOPLE, or /LOCATION

I have the following

```
'The/O\nSkoll/ORGANIZATION\nFoundation/ORGANIZATION\n,/O\nbased/O\nin/O\nSilicon/LOCATION\nValley/LOCATION\na'
```

And want the following

```
The\t/O\nSkoll\t/ORGANIZATION\nFoundation\tORGANIZATION\n
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work. How can I recall which org the regex captured?

```
x = str(t)
x = re.sub('\/(ORGANIZATION|LOCATION|PERSON|O)','\t\1', x)
```

My intermediate solution, but it'd be nice to have a one-liner.

```
x = re.sub(r'\/(ORGANIZATION)',r'\t\1', x)
x = re.sub(r'\/(LOCATION)', r'\t\1',x)
x = re.sub(r'\/(PERSON)',r'\t\1', x)
x = re.sub(r'\/(O)',r'\t\1', x)
```

Comment: where do `\nbased/O\nin/O\nSilicon/` etc.. go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
>>> t = 'The/O\nSkoll/ORGANIZATION\nFoundation/ORGANIZATION\n,/O\nbased/O\nin/O\nSilicon/LOCATION\nValley/LOCATION\na'
>>> re.sub(r'(/(?:ORGANIZATION|LOCATION|PERSON|O))',r'\t\1', t)
'The\t/O\nSkoll\t/ORGANIZATION\nFoundation\t/ORGANIZATION\n,\t/O\nbased\t/O\nin\t/O\nSilicon\t/LOCATION\nValley\t/LOCATION\na'
```

**Demo:** http://regex101.com/r/nB5dN3/1

Comment: can you help me understand a bit more why i need to put a parens around the whole thing? Why doesn't the first parens with the ?: signify the group?

Comment: @user3314418 The whole thing is in parenthesis because later on we will use this group in substitution('\1'). Here we actually have two groups, one is `/` and other is the one containing those words, but as we need just one group in the end we make the inner group a non-capturing one using `?:`, so we end up with one big outer group.

Comment: @user3314418 http://regex101.com/r/nB5dN3/2, Here as soon as I removed `?:` it captured 2 groups.

Answer (score 1):

Since `/O` covers your `/ORGANIZATION` case, no need to specify it again.

For the replacement string, you need to either pass a raw string, or escape the `\`. Therefore, **both of the following would work**:

```
x = re.sub( r'\/(O|LOCATION|PERSON)', r"\t\1", x )
x = re.sub( r'\/(O|LOCATION|PERSON)', "\\t\\1", x )
```

Comment: Thanks! can you help me understand the difference between your solution and mine, and why original attempt doesn't work?

Comment: @user3314418 Python treats raw strings (the one like `r''`) and normal strings differently.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want a [negative lookahead assertion](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) (syntax: `(?!...)` where `...` is something the assertion will try to match) to distinguish `/O` from `/ORGANIZATION`. Here's what I would suggest:

```
x = str(t)
x = re.sub(r'\/(ORGANIZATION|LOCATION|PERSON|O(?!R))','\t\\1', x)
```

Note that a lookahead assertion starts with `(?`, so it won't form a numbered group, so you still want to retrieve group in your replacement string.

Also note how I made the first string a raw string, but did NOT make the second string a raw string. I'm assuming that what you want in your replacement string is a tab character, rather than a backslash followed by a t, so I quoted the second backslash in the replacement but not the first. If you need more explanation of those backslashes, let me know.

Finally, if you want to keep the single forward slash in your replacement, you could put a second pair of grouping parentheses around the search regex as some people have suggested, but it's probably simpler to just add it to your replacement string, thus:

```
x = str(t)
x = re.sub(r'\/(ORGANIZATION|LOCATION|PERSON|O(?!R))','/\t\\1', x)
```

I think this is what you're looking for. Let us know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Using lookahead is overkill for such a simple issue.

Comment: @hjpotter92 - Yes, but it's a technique the OP probably didn't know and should learn, because it's highly useful in other situations. So even though `|` shortcuts and thus putting ORGANIZATION before O is sufficient, the OP would be well-served to know about lookahead (and lookbehind) assertions.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = 'The/O\nSkoll/ORGANIZATION\nFoun/LOLdation/ORGANIZATION\n,/O\nbased/O\nin/O\nSilicon/LOCATION\nValley/LOCATION\na'
x = re.sub("(/O|/ORGANIZATION|/PEOPLE|/LOCATION)", r"\t\1", str)
```

here, in just two lines~ but like hjpotter92 said, your /O covers organisation so there isn't really a need, but just to be specific.