# Insert string before first occurence of character

Tags: python

So basically I have this string `__int64 __fastcall(IOService *__hidden this);`, and I need to insert a word in between `__fastcall` (this could be anything) and `(IOService...` such as `__int64 __fastcall LmaoThisWorks(IOService *__hidden this);`.

I've thought about splitting the string but this seems a bit overkill. I'm hoping there's a simpler and shorter way of doing this:

```
type_declaration_fun = GetType(fun_addr) # Sample: '__int64 __fastcall(IOService *__hidden this)'
if type_declaration_fun:
    print(type_declaration_fun)
    type_declaration_fun = type_declaration_fun.split(' ')
    first_bit = ''
    others = ''
    funky_list = type_declaration_fun[1].split('(')
    for x in range(0, (len(funky_list))):
        if x == 0:
            first_bit = funky_list[0]
        else:
            others = others + funky_list[x]

    type_declaration_fun = type_declaration_fun[0] + ' ' + funky_list[0] + ' ' + final_addr_name + others
    type_declaration_fun = type_declaration_fun + ";"
    print(type_declaration_fun)
```

The code is not only crap,  but it doesn't quite work. Here's a sample output:

```
void *__fastcall(void *objToFree)
void *__fastcall IOFree_stub_IONetworkingFamilyvoid;
```

How could I make this work and cleaner?

Notice that there could be nested parentheses and other weird stuff, so you need to make sure that the name is added just before the first parenthesis.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex Python adding characters after a certain word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735384/regex-python-adding-characters-after-a-certain-word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you find the index of the character you need to insert before, you can use splicing to create your new string.

```
    string = 'abcdefg'
    string_to_insert = '123'
    insert_before_char = 'c'
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i] == insert_before_char:
            string = string[:i] + string_to_insert + string[i:]
            break
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method `replace()`:

```
s = 'ABCDEF'
ins = '$'
before = 'DE'
new_s = s.replace(before, ins + before, 1)

print(new_s)
# ABC$DEF
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
s = "__int64__fastcall(IOService *__hidden this);"
t = s.split("__fastcall",1)[0]+"anystring"+s.split("__fastcall",1)[1]
```

I get:

```
__int64__fastcallanystring(IOService *__hidden this);
```

I hope this is what you want. If not, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
   x='high speed'
    z='new text' 
    y = x.index('speed')
    x =x[:y] + z +x[y:]
print(x) 
>>> high new textspeed
```

this a quick example, please be aware that y inclusuve after the new string.

be Aware that you are changing the original string, or instead just declare a new string.

Answer (score 0):

Use `regex`.

```
In [1]: import re

        pattern = r'(?=\()'
        string = '__int64 __fastcall(IOService *__hidden this);'
        re.sub(pattern, 'pizza', string)

Out[1]: '__int64 __fastcallpizza(IOService *__hidden this);'
```

The `pattern` is a positive lookahead to match the first occurrence of `(`.