# Add a character at start of a regex match in Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, regex-group

I have a dataframe that has two columns, `id` and `text`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'Hello world 28'], [2, 'Hi how are you 9'], [3, '19 Hello']], columns=['id','text'])

   id   text
    1   Hello world 28
    2   Hi how are you 9
    3   19 Hello
```

In the `text` field, whenever there is a digit preceded by a space, I want to add a `#` before the digit. The resultant dataframe that I am looking for would be as follows:

```
   id   text
    1   Hello world #28
    2   Hi how are you #9
    3   19 Hello
```

I have tried the following method to capture the regex pattern and add the `#` character before the digit by following the example in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735384/regex-python-adding-characters-after-a-certain-word):

```
df['text'] = df['text'].replace(r'(\s\d{1,2})', "#\1", regex=True)
```

However, this gives me the following result and it replaces the entire digit with `#` instead of adding it at the start of the regex match:

```
   id   text
    1   Hello world #
    2   Hi how are you #
    3   19 Hello
```

Any pointers on how I can add the `#` character before a regex match? Thanks!

Comment: Note that `df['text'].replace(r"(\s)(\d{1,2})", r"\1#\2", regex=True)` will keep the original whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
df['text'].replace(r"\s(\d{1,2})", r" #\1", regex=True)
```

i.e. move the parantheses to surround the digit-part to capture the digit(s) to be reflected in `\1` and make the replacing string raw by `r` to escape the slash in `\1` (and also put a space before `#`)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to preserve original whitespace use 2 groups:

```py
df['text'].replace(r"(\s)(\d{1,2})", r"\1#\2", regex=True)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/AlRzni/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{1,2}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 2 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
```